# How to read a SUM() grouping function in a PHP SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this

```
"SELECT SUM( state ) FROM `vote` WHERE id ='5'"
```

now when add it in php, how i can do

```
$xx= mysql_fetch_array(
    mysql_query("SELECT SUM( state ) FROM `vote` WHERE id ='5'")
);
```

Can I can do it like that:

```
echo $xx['SUM( state )'];
```

Comment: Everybody copy&pasted the same mistake into his answer.... you should write `WHERE id=...`

Comment: @extraneon: At least some one cares about quality ;)

Comment: @Felix, nah, but I don't like parsing exceptions in my head. Gives me a headache.

Answer (score 8):

Give SUM( state ) an alias.

```
SELECT SUM( state ) AS SummedState FROM `vote` WHERE id ='5'
```

Now, reference the alias

```
echo $xx['SummedState']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an alias in your SQL query :

```
"SELECT SUM( state ) as result FROM `vote` WHEREid ='5'"
```

*Note the "`as column_name`" I added in the query.*

And, then, you'll be able to access the "result" column from your PHP code :

```
echo $xx['result'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alias for SUM(state):

```
"SELECT SUM(state) AS state_sum FROM `vote` WHERE id ='5'"
```

Then you would be able to reference it as follows:

```
echo $xx['state_sum']
```